# How can I attach a SQLite ID to a Spinner object in android?

Tags: android

I want to pull a couple columns from a database and add those to the spinner, but I want the _id of the row to be hidden in there somewhere too.  Take partial sample code below for example:

```
    public void fillProfileSpinner()
    {
        String query = "SELECT _id,fruit_type,weight,colour FROM fruits;";
        SQLiteDatabase profileDatabase = fruitCakes.database.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = profileDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        try {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do
            {
                String fruitType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fruit_type"));
                double weight = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("weight"));
                String colour = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("colour"));
                fruitAdapter.add(colour + " " + weight + " " + fruit_type);
            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cursor.deactivate();
        cursor.close();
        profileDatabase.close();
}
```

I believe this is what I'm looking for, however I find it very confusing:
[Android Spinners, say I pull spinner selections from SQL, can I also add their SQL _id's to the spinner values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983514/android-spinners-say-i-pull-spinner-selections-from-sql-can-i-also-add-their-sq)

How can I get the _id column in there somewhere, so that is accessible from some method in the spinner object?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a scenario where your `_ID` value is not already directly available to you or derivable via the position:

- In `onListItemClick()` of a `ListActivity`, it is the `id` parameter
- In `onItemClick()` of a `OnItemClickListener`, it is the `id` parameter
- Anywhere else that you have a position (e.g., `getView()` of a `ListAdapter`), call `moveToPosition()` on your `Cursor` and retrieve your `_ID` that way